# Android whats new screen

Tags: android, json, mobile

I am re-pharsing my question to avoid negative points.  I am aware of web view, dialogs, popups, notifications.  if you have some other ideas please let me know.
I am working on a very big android application, in which I have to add some popup kind of thing, which tells the user what we have updated for this version.  Kind of like, what bugs are fixed or whats new things are added.

The window have to be populated once or twice and it have to have user interactions, like click on the link, or contact us, or click on the image to go to some page inside the app.  Please let me know any good ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You definitively should give a look to the `AlertDialog` class

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html

This is basically the class used to display a message and get the ok/cancel/anything answer from the user. But it's customizable and you can make more or less what you want according to which button is pressed by the user.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply.  I wanted a link inside the page, like contact us, and if the user clicks on it, it should go to the contact page in the app.  Can you suggest something for that.  Thanks